# Who says what in the Babylon 5 Season 5 intro?

Tags: babylon-5, theme-music

In seasons 4 and 5, rather then just one person speaking, a large number of people speak.  Who says what in the season 5 intro?

Comment: Season 4 [answered here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/178888/31394).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike season 4, everything in this one are quotes from earlier episodes:

**2258**

"And so it begins." – Kosh

"There is a hole in your mind." – Minbari Assassin

"What do you want?" – Mr. Morden

"No one here is exactly what he appears." – G'Kar

"Nothing's the same anymore." – Jeffrey Sinclair

**2259**

"Commander Sinclair is being reassigned." – William Hague

"Why don't you eliminate the entire Narn homeworld while you're at it?" – Londo Mollari

"I see a great hand reaching out of the stars." – Elric

"Who are you?" – Sebastian

**2260**

"President Clark has signed a decree today declaring martial law." – ISN News Caster

"These orders have forced us to declare independence." – John Sheridan

"Weapon supplies." – Alfred Bester

"Unless your people get off their encounter-suited butts and do something." – John Sheridan

"You're the one who was." – Zathras

"If you go to Z'ha'dum you will die." – Kosh

**2261**

"Why are you here?" – Lorien

"Do you have anything worth living for?" – Lorien

"I think of my beautiful city in flames." – Delenn

"Giants in the playground." – John Sheridan

"Now get the hell out of our galaxy!" – John Sheridan

"We are here to place President Clark under arrest." – John Sheridan

I copied this from babylon5.fandom.com, but it appears to be correct.